# Ionic 2 : iOS Push notification - Register ID Error

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, ionic2

I have to build an Ionic 2 app that include push notification (iOS and Android). I had successfull implement push notification for the android device with firebase. But now, I have some problems with iOS devices.

When I try to add my app ID in https://developer.apple.com/ I have this error :

```
There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.

An App ID with Identifier 'com.ionicframework.myappXXXXX' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

It appear when I try to submit this form : 
[image]

myapp is the name of my Application and XXXXX the number.

I have find this ID in my config.xml from my Ionic projet.
I don't understand why I have this error because I can easly build my app from xcode.

Anyone have an Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Automatically manage signing` check on in your Xcode settings, it will automatically create bundle identifier with whatever is there in Xcode target settings. Here in this example, I'm assuming the same thing happened. That's why it might be saying that it is not available. Check your developer portal whether it's already there are not. If it's there, use the same bundle id while creating push notification certificate.

Comment: I verified in my developer portal my app isn't already there.

Comment: What is the error now you are getting while creating explicit ID? can you give more insight into this? Otherwise you can create any explicit id you want to use and put the same ID in your app settings

Comment: You mean I can change my app ID in developer.apple.com (invente it), and use my invented ID in my config.xml file in my Ionic 2 project ?

Comment: Yes exactly. It should be unique. It should not match with any other app bundle id.

Comment: Oh ok ! I will try that. But I will have some problem with my android version I think ? I already use this bundle ID for firebase.

Comment: I think you will have separate, separate IDs for both versions.